# Condition to check if two planes form the boundary of the same object

Tags: computational-geometry, 3d-reconstruction

[image]I am trying to figure out an algorithm to determine if the planes detected by a depth sensor can be said to be part of the same 3d object.

I was reading a paper "Plane-Based Optimization of Geometry and Texture for RGB-D Reconstruction of Indoor Scenes" by C. Wang and X. Guo where they where they present a novel approach of adaptive planes. They essentially use 3 conditions:
1. Angle between two plane normals are small:
2. Average distance between two planes is small:
3. Angle between the ray connecting two plane centers and each plane normal is as close as possible to 90◦

I have com up with the following two conditions:
1. The normals for the two planes should be perpendicular to each other. (I am making an assumption here that the 3D object is a cuboid).
2. Average distance between two planes is small. (from the paper)

What other conditions could be necessary and sufficient to conclude this? Any other research papers or documentation for this would greatly help.

Comment: Theory is best asked here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Water This is very much not a theory question.

Comment: @SunilNair what do you define as a "plane" here? A plane is normally an infinite flat region, it doesn't have boundaries like in your drawing, and there's no notion of "distance" between two planes (if they're not parallel, they intersect so distance is zero).

Comment: As I mentioned, the planes are actually planar surfaces, detected by a depth sensor like Kinect.

Comment: @Sneftel What _exactly_ is theory to you then? Discussing the mathematical underpinnings of an algorithm in an academic research paper in computer vision, tagging it as `computational-geometry`, and then asking for academic papers without even mentioning or talking about code... this belongs on some other stack exchange (CS, math, etc). CS theory is fine (maybe not ideal) as he's discussing academic/mathematical things from a computer vision (aka: CS) research paper. Why don't you want this to be where people more tailored to answering this question can see it? This site is for programming.

Comment: @Water thanks. I will post it on the link you provided.

Comment: @SunilNair Note that there may be multiple stack exchanges that work. For example https://math.stackexchange.com/ may be more up your alley, there's a bunch of them. In short, my goal is to make sure you get your question to the _correct_ people, because it's almost certain that asking here will reduce the amount of people who can answer your question since most people who go through stack overflow are programmers. The academic people who can help you are likely in much higher concentration on the other exchange sites. Don't limit yourself only to my links, there may be a comp-vision one too.